# Glympse API - Two Bugs?

Tags: glympse

I have two issues currently with the Glympse Lite iOS API.

1. For some reason, when I add the GlympseKitLite.embeddedframework to my project, my table view cell disclosure indicator (UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator) & UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark do not appear in various table views throughoug my app (except when the cell is highlighted).  It may be that the indicator is actually white but I have a white table view cell background.  This is odd behavior.  The embeddedframework seems to be the root cause (as soon as I delete it, the accessory views resume normal behavior).
2. The "dismiss" button in the lower right of the "Generating Glympse" screen seems to be non-functional.  This is reproducible using the demo apps.  Place the phone in airplane mode before sending a glympse.  Once the send button is pressed, there's no way to exit the "Generating Glympse" screen (without exiting airplane mode).

Any help with these two issues would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it! Both issues are noted. We will investigate it and notify you when it is fixed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support question and therefore should be directed to your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Both issues mentioned above were fixed in SDK build 1.0.2. 
It is currently available at developer.glympse.com.